# Templates and headers

Tags: c++, templates

So do any of the future standards of c++ plan to resolve the issue of having to combine the declaration and implementation?

Comment: In fact, while the current C++ language standard does resolve this issue, the forthcoming revision to the C++ language standard, C++0x, unresolves it.

Comment: @James - Are you referring to the export keyword?

Comment: @James: Export was not merely deprecated from C++0x; they actually removed it _without_ deprecating it. Probably because very few compilers implemented it, and even those had to basically rearchitect their compilers in order to do so.

Comment: @Mehrdad - Eh... spelling... who needs it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a very good reason why the template implementation needs to go into the header. A template is not code - it's only a *template* for the automatic *generation* of code. The code doesn't get created until you try to use it with the template parameters filled in. The compiler needs to have the full template body in order to fill in the blanks and get working code.

Comment: I understand that... I was just hoping people who are MUCH smarter than me had some clevor way of getting around the issue.

Answer (score 0):

C++0x does not. Other future standard versions haven't even begun being drafted yet.